# Which one is correct: "the packaging that your phone came in" or "the packaging that your phone came with"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which one is correct: *the packaging that your phone came in* or *the packaging that your phone came with*? For example:

> If you want to send the phone back and get refunded, you have to have the packaging that your phone came **in**/**with**.

Are both natural and correct?

Comment: It would be more natural to use _in_. The packaging had the purpose of protecting the phone in transit, it didn't come with it like some kind of accessory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "in" sounds more natural. Here is my reasoning:

In this context, "with" is too broad. Although the packaging did come *with* the phone, the phone was also *in* the box. Meanwhile, there are likely some things that came *with* the phone that do not need to be sent back for the return.

That being said, both are natural enough and I do not think that *anyone* would wince upon hearing "with" instead of "in".